# ReferenceError: document is not defined in bg.js file when migrating chrome extension to MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

I am migrating my chrome extension code from Manifest V2 to V3. However, I get a "ReferenceError: document is not defined" in line 9 of my bg.js file. Does anyone recognize why? It worked fine in MV2

**bg.js**

```
   //Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {

  if(msg.name == "playTrack"){

    //...
    var trackName = msg.track;
    var audioEle = document.querySelector('.audio-element');
    audioEle.src = 'track-'+trackName+'.mp3';
    audioEle.play();

  }

  if(msg.name == "pauseTrack"){

    var audioEle = document.querySelector('.audio-element');
    audioEle.pause();
  }

});
```

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "name": "Sizzo",
  "version": "0.01",
  "description": "Sizzo - Stay flawless with the perfect audio reminders",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Sizzo",
        "default_popup": "popout.html"
    },
  "background":{
    "service_worker": "bg.js"
  },
  "icons": { "48": "icon48.jpg",
             "128": "icon128.jpg" },
  "manifest_version": 3
}
```

**popout.js**

```
   document.querySelector('button.play').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var SelTrack = document.querySelector('select').value;

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name: "playTrack", track: SelTrack});

});


document.querySelector('button.pause').addEventListener('click', function(){

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name: "pauseTrack"});

});
```

Comment: Service workers don't have DOM things like document or audio. ManifestV3 doesn't support background audio yet.

Answer (score 0):

MV3 background workers are Service Workers, they're not documents and lack DOM APIs.

Firefox will support regular background **pages** even in MV3, but in Chrome you would have to use `offscreen` documents to access DOM APIs

- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/Offscreen-Documents-in-Manifest-v3/
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/

Something like:

```js
// background-worker.js
chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL('off_screen.html'),
  reasons: ['AUDIO_PLAYBACK'],
  justification: 'Playing audio on the user’s request',
});
```

```html
// off_screen.html
<script src="off_screen.js">
```

```js
// off_screen.js
new Audio('elevator-music.mp3').play()
```